# Encountering issues while running "AccountEditor" hybrid mobile app

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

I installed SalesforceSDK and tried running the sample hybrid app "Account Editor"(AccountEditor.html), it is throwing an error as "Error calling method on NPObject". A blank white screen occurs after logging in.. Any Ideas? 
But the other two HTML files in the app are working..

Comment: Is this iOS or Android? Device or Emulator? Which OS Version?

Comment: Android... In Emulator.. Using Eclipse.. ADT version 22..